# Memory issue in converting static writeCallBack function into non-static member function in C++ way of cURL

Tags: c++11, curl, callback

I would like to implement a write call back function of cURL in a non-static member function.

While calling this method it throws an `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` error. But if I use it in a static method it works fine.

Non-static member function:

```
size_t dataFromWebService :: WriteCallback(void *contentsPtr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string stream, void *classPointer)
{
    std::cout<<"Called write call back" <<std::endl;

    return static_cast<dataFromWebService*>(classPointer)->WriteCallbackImpl(contentsPtr, size, nmemb, stream);        
}

size_t dataFromWebService :: WriteCallbackImpl(void *contentsPtr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string stream)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = chunk1;//(struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

    mem->memory = (char*)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if(mem->memory == NULL) {
        /* out of memory! */
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contentsPtr, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;        
}
```

And I invoked:

```
std::string myData;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &dataFromWebService::WriteCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &myData);
```

While debugging I got:

```
size    size_t  419      
nmemb   size_t  140734799803520        
realsize    size_t  58967881117674880
```

The equivalent static method is:

```
static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp, struct MemoryStruct *myChunk)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = myChunk;//(struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

    mem->memory = (char*)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if(mem->memory == NULL) {
        /* out of memory! */
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}
```

I invoked:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &chunk);
```

The debug values are:

```
size    size_t  1        
nmemb   size_t  419    
realsize    size_t  2
```

The MemoryStruct:

```
struct MemoryStruct
{
char *memory;
size_t size;
};
```

Why am I getting a larger `nmemb` value for the non-static member function for the same data? What is wrong?

Comment: In your example, which are non-static member functions - `WriteCallback`, `WriteCallbackImpl`, both or neither? Why are you casting `classPointer` to `dataFromWebService*`, when what you set with `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` is `std::string*`?

Comment: The right way to do it is - set a *static* member function as `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, and `this` pointer as `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`. The static function must have the signature that `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` expects: `size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);` (you can't just make up extra parameters). The static function would cast `userdata` pointer back to `YourClass*`, and call a non-static member through that pointer. The non-static member can then do all the work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik   Thanks for the reply. Both `WriteCallback ` `WriteCallbackImpl `are non static member functions. I don’t understand your next question.

Comment: Then your code is just plain wrong, and has no hope of working. I explained how to do it right. Have you tried that?

Comment: (static member)`size_t dataFromWebService :: WriteCallback(void *contentsPtr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string stream, void *classPointer)
{      return static_cast<dataFromWebService*>(classPointer)->WriteCallbackImpl(contentsPtr,  size,  nmemb,  stream);       
}`

Comment: I and called ` curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &dataFromWebService::WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this); ` Sorry I could not send messages altogether in a single response.

Comment: This works fine. but why I had weird `nmemb` size?. ( I earlier wants to convert the data into a string. thats why I added string in `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` but i failed to convert into a string member variable )

Comment: Which part of *"The static function must have the signature that `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` expects"* do you find unclear? `string stream` parameter shouldn't be there. It should be `size_t dataFromWebService :: WriteCallback(void *contentsPtr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *classPointer);` What string do you expect libcurl to pass to you?

Comment: Oh sorry I miscopied the content from my IDE.  (static member) ` size_t dataFromWebService :: WriteCallback(void *contentsPtr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *classPointer)
{    return static_cast<dataFromWebService*>(classPointer)->WriteCallbackImpl(contentsPtr,  size,  nmemb);    
} ` I understand that this method only returns size_t.

Comment: The callback should return `nmemb` on success, and any smaller value (usually 0) to indicate failure.

Comment: But still i don’t understand why a non static method make ` size    size_t  419      
nmemb   size_t  140734799803520  ` this big mess. The main functionality of a static method is that it can be called without instance right? (Correct me if i am wrong )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you still talking about a case where a non-static method is set directly with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`? This exhibits undefined behavior, just don't do that. Or are you now saying that you get unexpected values when using a static method? In your original question, you said that worked for you, so what changed since then? After all the plot twists, I'm no longer sure what code you are running, or what problems (if any) you are having with it.

Comment: I dint explained the question well. After changed ` non static member CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION ` into  `static member CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION ` it works fine.     _ Are you still talking about a case where a non-static method is set directly with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION?_ yes I just would like to know the reason thats it. Leave this. Now everything works fine. @Igor Tandetnik